# Set first column of table as link

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I am loading my table from mysql and I want to make first column link. I mean link to another form.  I want to display student details and when click on a name program will open a new form and display all info about student. Anyone have any idea about how to do?

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
MySqlDataAdapter adapsql = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT  name, surname, dob, sex, nationality, mobile, notes FROM student", connection);
adapsql.Fill(table);
dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
int x = (dataGridView1.RowCount)-1;
label21.Text = Convert.ToString(x);

cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM reservation";

MySqlDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (!Reader.HasRows) return;
while (Reader.Read())
{
    reservation.Add(Convert.ToInt16(GetDBString("roomID", Reader)));

}
Reader.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle this under the following event:

```
dataGridView1_CellClick
```

Get the CurrentCell value of the datagridiview and use this information to open your second form and add the required information to the fields you have there.

Sample code:

```
if (this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null) 
{
    string valueofcell=dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
    // Raise the corresponding form as per you required
}
```